# How should I name a table column that shows duration?

Tags: word-choice

I have a table with a column that shows when a specific entry was modified. It used to be just the date and time the modification occurred, for example "Modified at: May 08 2019 13:56:51".

Now I want to display how much time has passed since the modification, like so "6 second" or "4 hours". But now the field name "Modified at" doesn't work, how should I fix the name?

Thanks!

Comment: "Time since last modified:" or "Modified...ago" if that's possible

Comment: @TimFoster please feel free to add this as an answer. Also, is the ellipsis necessary in "Modified...ago"?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the term

> Time since last modified:

or perhaps

> Time since last modification:

However, this feels a bit long for a column title.

If there is a way to have the field name integrated with the time itself, then you could use "Modified...ago". For example, if the time was 8 hours, the field entry for that item would read:

> Modified 8 hours ago

And that way you could keep the column title fairly simple, as just "Modified". However, this may be difficult, depending what software you are using.